# Returning Only the Most Recent Value of a Rolling Average SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

I am working on generating a rolling average for all of the minimum values from a particular time frame. The query I have written so far calculates the minimum value from each period, and then creates a rolling average of those minimums partitioned by the facility name. The problem is whenever I try to just return the value of the rolling average at the most recent date, instead of giving me the rolling average, I just get the minimum value at that date. This is what my query looks like:

```
   F.normalized_facility_id, F.name, F.period_end_date, F.minimum, 
   avg(minimum) OVER (PARTITION BY F.normalized_facility_id
       ORDER BY period_end_date
       ROWS BETWEEN 23 preceding and current ROW) as RollingMinimumAvg
FROM
(
   --This Select statement is designed to calculate the minimum benzene concentration from each sample period from each refinery.
   SELECT  
       F.normalized_facility_id, F.name, SR.report_id, RP.period_end_date,
       min(benzene_concentration) AS minimum
   FROM PassiveBenzene.sampler_results SR
   INNER JOIN PassiveBenzene.report_periods RP
       ON SR.period_id = RP.period_id
   INNER JOIN PassiveBenzene.report R
       ON SR.report_id = R.report_id
   INNER JOIN PassiveBenzene.facility F
       ON R.facility_id = F.facility_id
   GROUP BY F.normalized_facility_id, F.name, SR.report_id, RP.period_end_date
) as F
ORDER BY F.normalized_facility_id, F.period_end_date DESC, RollingMinimumAvg
```

The result from this is the minimum from every period along with the rolling average minimum instead of the rolling average minimum value at the most recent date period for each facility. When I try to add a clause that returns the rolling average at the maximum date value, it just returns the minimum value at that date and not the rolling average minimum that was calculated. If I create a third query around my original and subqueries, that queries for the rolling average minimum at the maximum date value, would that achieve what I am trying to look for? **Is it even possible to only return the most recent value of a rolling average in SQLServer?**

Comment: Firstly, it is generally NOT a good idea to post a fragment of a query. And it IS a good idea to reduce your problem to help encourage others to help you. But this seems like a typical "select first in group" issue - a phrase you can search on. Add row_number into your resultset and select the rows where that value is 1. Given the GROUP BY clause I will guess that you want one row per facility rather than just 1 single row.

Comment: I will add that you could put your current query in a view and then just select those rows where <period = May 31 2022> (as an example). There are usually different ways to accomplish the same goal using SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your query as a subquery then number them by descendig date within each facility, and choose the first one:

```
SELECT
   F2.normalized_facility_id, F2.name, F2.period_end_date, F2.minimum 
FROM (
        SELECT 
            F1.*
            , Seq=row_number() over 
                   (partition by F1.normalized_facility_id 
                    order by F1.period_end_date desc)
        FROM
          (
            -- insert Your Query ( less the ORDER BY part) here
          ) F1
    ) F2
where F2.Seq=1 
ORDER BY F2.normalized_facility_id, F2.period_end_date DESC, F2.RollingMinimumAvg
```